# Android ScrollView add data on end scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I've read a lot of posts but never find solution for my problem which is:
I have LinearLayout inside ScrollView. LinearLayout containt inflated Layout. At the end I have button. When user clicks on the button it inflates more Layouts (adds more table rows). Now, I want to remove the button and call its function when user scrolls to bottom.

--edited--

Here is part of my code...

```
public void showRows(){
    try {
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor select = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * from TRANSACTIONS "+
          "limit "+nRow+",20", null);

        if (select.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
                View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
                item.addView(child);

                TextView txt = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                txt.setText(select.getString(0));

            } while (select.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reading error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        mydb.close();

        if(nRow+11 <= nTotalRows){
            LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
            child_more = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transaction_more, null);
            item.addView(child_more);
            bMore = (Button) child_more.findViewById(R.id.bMore);
            bMore.setOnClickListener(this);

            // on click nRow = nRow + 20 ... and calls again the same function

            //TODO...
            //...remove button but call more if ScrollView reachs end...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code so I have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use ListView for this case. You'll be able to detect when last item was shown and call the same method that button's click called.
You can hide button by calling bMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);